# Why does Spring send back a session cookie even if authentication fails

Tags: spring-security, session-cookies

I have setup Spring security like this

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable();

    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/signup").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .successHandler(no_redirect_success_handler)
            .permitAll();

}
```

I am using an in-memory db (hsqldb), so all user registration details are lost each time I launch the application.

Using curl, I issue this request:

```
curl -v -X POST --data "username=abc@x.com&password=abcd" "localhost:8080/login"
```

Since the above username/password combination does not exist, Spring sends back 302 response containing the following:

```
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=0B741B948AEFFF620573310732796E85; Path=/; HttpOnly
Location: http://localhost:8080/login?error
```

Since the authentication failed, why should Spring send a session cookie? Shouldn't it be sent only if authentication succeeds?